# Mysterious EXC_BAD_ACCESS in simple code

Tags: swift, xcode, exc-bad-access

I have some project where I created convenient architecture for my needing and all things was fine until I encountered mysterious crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` at runtime. I posted [here](https://gist.github.com/Azat92/2941200d9c1cc5d91d54e992660b7fc8) the smallest code which represents the issue and here is the explanation:

Imagine some `protocol` and another one which is first's child:

```
protocol Base {

    static var key: String { get }
}

protocol BaseChild: Base {

}
```

And here is some simple implementation:

```
struct ChildEntity: BaseChild {

    static var key: String {
        return "key"
    }
}
```

Then, I have some class which works with such entities:

```
class Worker {

    static var defaultWorker: Worker? // will explain later

    func work<T: Base>(entity: T) {
        print(T.key)
    }
}
```

And I also have some subclass of `Worker`:

```
class ChildWorker: Worker {

    override func work<T: BaseChild>(entity: T) {
        print(T.key)
    }
}
```

So far so good. Then I added static `defaultWorker` var to my `Worker` class to make access to my default worker easier, this allows me to create an extension for my `Base` protocol which will work with my `defaultWorker`:

```
extension Base {

    func work() {
        Worker.defaultWorker?.work(entity: self)
    }
}
```

However this generates `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` at runtime. Here is simple usage:

```
class Test {

    static func run() {
        let object = ChildEntity()
        let worker = ChildWorker()
        worker.work(entity: object) // OK here

        Worker.defaultWorker = worker 
        object.work() // EXC_BAD_ACCESS here
    }
}
```

I tested this on both Xcode 8 and Xcode 9 with Swift 3 and Swift 4. Please help me solve this issue

Comment: Try doing `object.work` (removing `()`) ... or leaving that and doing `Test.run`

Comment: @l'L'l thank you but what is the sense of doing that? I can achieve the same result with simply commenting this line out. I mean removing brackets will stop executing my function, but I need it to work

Comment: It's helpful to what is happening... the error is in the line `Worker.defaultWorker?.work(entity: self)`

Comment: More specifically I think it's `defaultWorker?` which ends up in an infinite loop probably. Not sure if this would work, but maybe try something like `Worker.init().work(entity: self)`...

Comment: @l'L'l yes it works if I will create new instance of `Worker`, but I need something like default worker to avoid passing reference to it everywhere. And there is no reason for infinite loop because `work` function in `Worker` doesn't do anything with instance itself. Also, if you put that code in project and try to run, stack trace is couple of lines, not long as it would be in infinite call case

Comment: @l'L'l if in `ChildWorker` you replace `work` function body with `print(entity)` then this thing will work, so there is no infinite loop or smth like so, there is something strange in `T.key` call itself

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you override `func work<T: Base>(entity: T)` to `override func work<T: BaseChild >(entity: T)`?

Is not that supposed to be `override func work<T: Base>(entity: T)`?

Comment: I wanted that my child worker would work only with `BaseChild` instances, so I tried to narrow possible calls at the compiler level. But when I do so it says that I am missing `override` keyword and then compiler is happy